# converting decimal to binary without the bin() function in python

Tags: python, binary, decimal

I've looked into other solutions online and my own and all of them gave the exact same output, and thats my terminal being spammed with 1's.

this is my code, (I'm very new to coding so please forgive any clear cut mistakes :I)

```
def decimaltobinary(numb):
    bit = []
    x = numb // 2
    while numb > 1:
      y = x // 2
      bit.append(y)
```

this is the code I found online which gave the exact same output

```
def trans(x):
    if x == 0: return [0]
    bit = []
    while x:
        bit.append(x % 2)
        x >>= 1
    return bit[::-1]
```

Comment: Is your question why your code results in an infinite loop? It doesn't spam the terminal though.

Comment: You never update `numb` in your ` while numb > 1:` loop.

Comment: Nitpick: there's not really any "decimal" here: you're converting a Python `int` to its binary representation in the form of a list of bits. (That Python `int` happens to be stored internally in binary, not decimal, but that's mostly irrelevant.)

Comment: For `trans`, what values are you calling it with? Is the input `x` always nonnegative? For a negative `x`, it would indeed create an infinite sequence, all but finitely many entries of which would be `1`s.